# Why im getting this error trying to update my profile picture?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, photo

Hello everyone im getting a error when  im trying to update my profile picture in flutter .

```
I/BitmapCropTask(22569): Should crop: true
E/flutter (22569): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _MeinAccountState#51c31(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (22569): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (22569): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (22569): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (22569): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1054:9)
E/flutter (22569): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1089:6)
E/flutter (22569): #2      _MeinAccountState._cropImage (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/seitenleiste/meinacount.dart:464:7)
E/flutter (22569): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22569): 
I/OpenGLRenderer(22569): Davey! duration=900ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=404683725160222, Vsync=404683808493552, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=404683823245510, AnimationStart=404683823373510, PerformTraversalsStart=404683823679510, DrawStart=404684494965510, SyncQueued=404684496166510, SyncStart=404684547432510, IssueDrawCommandsStart=404684555113510, SwapBuffers=404684565824510, FrameCompleted=404684677131510, DequeueBufferDuration=43941000, QueueBufferDuration=55381000, GpuCompleted=0, 
I/OpenGLRenderer(22569): Davey! duration=1032ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=404683725160222, Vsync=404683808493552, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=404683823245510, AnimationStart=404683823373510, PerformTraversalsStart=404683823679510, DrawStart=404684699540510, SyncQueued=404684700293510, SyncStart=404684783237510, IssueDrawCommandsStart=404684795352510, SwapBuffers=404684822351510, FrameCompleted=404684840233510, DequeueBufferDuration=1873000, QueueBufferDuration=12800000, GpuCompleted=470041226614272,
```

But im not using timer inside this class.
MY code is very long so please tell me if you need the hole code it like about 400 lines or maybe if you need an exact piece
What think the problem is maybe her because it all works until I tried to let user upload picture.

```
class MeinAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/MeinAccount';

  @override
  _MeinAccountState createState() => _MeinAccountState();
}

class _MeinAccountState extends State<MeinAccount> {
  File _pickedImage;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
```

```
 Future _loadPicker(ImageSource source) async {
    final picked = await picker.getImage(source: source);
    if (this.mounted) { // This checks if the widget is still in the tree
      setState(()  {
        setState(() {
      if (picked != null) {
        _cropImage(picked);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
      });
    }
  }
  _cropImage(PickedFile picked) async {
    File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: picked.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4
        ],
      maxWidth: 800,
    );
    if (cropped != null) {
      setState(() {
        _pickedImage = cropped;
      });
    }
  }

  void _showPickOptionsDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Pick from Gallery"),
              onTap: () {
                _loadPicker(ImageSource.gallery);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Take a picture"),
              onTap: () {
                _loadPicker(ImageSource.camera);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Heres the error :

```
if (cropped != null) {
      setState(() {
        _pickedImage = cropped;
      });
    }
```

The error is away but here's what it shows now

```
D/MediaScannerConnection(26319): Scanned /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/DENYAGROUP2021.com/files/Pictures/7d96cd78-0a82-47f0-b27d-96246635bc682265191042833866810.jpg to null
D/EGL_emulation(26319): eglCreateContext: 0xf0caca10: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/BitmapLoadUtils(26319): maxBitmapSize: 2792
D/BitmapWorkerTask(26319): Uri scheme: file
I/OpenGLRenderer(26319): Davey! duration=1158ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=412117758196194, Vsync=412118108196180, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=412118118324710, AnimationStart=412118118404710, PerformTraversalsStart=412118151854710, DrawStart=412118706779710, SyncQueued=412118724588710, SyncStart=412118746374710, IssueDrawCommandsStart=412118747987710, SwapBuffers=412118918505710, FrameCompleted=412118938578710, DequeueBufferDuration=696000, QueueBufferDuration=8362000, GpuCompleted=411534615855710, 
I/Choreographer(26319): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer(26319): Davey! duration=1014ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=412118724868043, Vsync=412119608201341, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=412119616194710, AnimationStart=412119616351710, PerformTraversalsStart=412119617536710, DrawStart=412119625786710, SyncQueued=412119634157710, SyncStart=412119642144710, IssueDrawCommandsStart=412119642624710, SwapBuffers=412119673457710, FrameCompleted=412119747758710, DequeueBufferDuration=3320000, QueueBufferDuration=12352000, GpuCompleted=411534824754710, 
D/TransformImageView(26319): Image size: [960:1280]
I/BitmapCropTask(26319): Should crop: false
``
```

Comment: Can you tell me which line exactly are you having this error?

Comment: I sont know maybe its where I call set state

Comment: Yes, click in this line in your error: "E/flutter (22569): #2      _MeinAccountState._cropImage (package:projectandroidstudiodenya/seitenleiste/meinacount.dart:464:7)" and see  where it takes you, after that, show me the code, pls.

Comment: Ok please check code I edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (cropped != null) {
    if (this.mounted) { // This check whether the state object is in tree
      setState(() {
        _pickedImage = cropped;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error is away but look at my post I updated it .It still not showing the picture please check

Comment: Man, your last update does not indicate errors, you may be having logic problems in your code

Comment: No way my code was working fine until I tried to use update user profile picture

Comment: Are there any errors appearing on the screen of your virtual device?

Comment: I figure it out it was the Navigator.of.(context).pop I dont know why actually but this fix it .

Comment: Good, have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks men you too:)

Answer (score 0):

In short, your widget is no longer in the tree because of shenanigans with the async/await.

An easy fix is just to check if your widget is in the tree by using:

```dart
 if (this.mounted) { // This checks if the widget is still in the tree 
      setState(() {
      // [YOUR CODE HERE]
      });
    }
```

Comment: The error is away but look at my post I updated it .It still not showing the picture please check